# Justified-Gallery in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, javascript

I am trying to implement Justified-Gallery: http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/ in my Drupal 7 website.

I linked justifiedGallery.min.css and jquery.justifiedGallery.min.js.

The thumbs are generated with [Node Gallery](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_gallery) module.

In my script.js I call

```
Drupal.behaviors.my_custom_behavior = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {
    $('.gallery').justifiedGallery();
  }
};
```

but on the page only the loading animation shows, the divs holding the thumbs remain with opacity:0 and are not arranged in grid... Interestingly all elements are assigned the respective styles by the script, so I think the script is not kicking-in properly.

I also tried putting

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.gallery').justifiedGallery();
 });
```

but again no luck...

Both codes are wrapped in the

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
...
})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is it throwing any error?

Comment: Hi, nope, no error, just the loading animation shows and no further action. As if its stuck there.

Comment: That's weird. Are you talking about an error in the browser or in the console tab of the developer tool?

Comment: in the console tab...

Comment: In your last code line, you open `{` but never close it. If that's really the case, and you see no error in JS console, you should use another browser - because it is an error and should fail pretty loudly.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I know, it just that I did not copy-paste the whole thing, just the beginning of the code. Everything is closed properly and in all that I know must be working...

That's the full code I use, but its not working:

Drupal.behaviors.my_custom_behavior = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {
 $('.gallery').justifiedGallery();
  }
};

and than I use this one, also no good:

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.gallery').justifiedGallery();
});

of course wrapped in the (function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) { ... })(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);

Comment: please don't add code to comments - add that code properly formatted to the question as an edit for easier viewing

Comment: Got it up online somewhere so we can have a look?

Comment: no, unfortunately its not online :(